# FxLayoutAlign center is working

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material2

I am using material angular and using below code but make center

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <span class="mat-display-2">Hello, Lemonite!</span>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
  <span class="mat-display-2">Hello, Lemonite!</span>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
</div>
<div style="margin: 50px;"></div>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <span class="mat-display-2" style="margin: 0;">Hello, Lemonite!</span>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/center-test?file=app/app.component.html

Also if you try to position in different ways you check out the interactive demo: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Answer (score 2):

I know the book you're reading with that question. It doesn't mention it, but you have to import FlexLayoutModule in your material module file.